Include attributes in document.createElement for custom elements
I'm trying to dynamically add a custom element I created, but it's not generating them properly.
div-item declaration:
class Item extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.src = this.getAttribute("src");
        this.link = this.getAttribute("href");
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
        this.text = this.textContent.trim();

        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>/* Styles excluded */</style>
        <div>
            <a href='${this.link}'>
                <div class="bg">
                    <img src="${this.src}" alt="${this.text}">
                </div>
                <p>${this.text}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('div-item', Item);

Javascript generating:
function createDivItems() {
  // Get all elements with the class name "row"
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

  // Iterate over each row element
  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    var row = rows[j];

    // Remove all existing div-item elements from the row
    row.innerHTML = '';

    // Create and add elements based on the window width
    for (var i = 0; i < (window.innerWidth - 60); i += 120) {
      // Create a new custom element
      var elem = document.createElement("div-item", {"src": '<?php echo "assets/not found.png"; ?>', "href": '<?php echo "/newPage.php"; -- placeholders for implementing the shop system ?>'});

      // Set attributes for the custom element
      elem.setAttribute("src", '<?php echo "assets/not found.png"; ?>');
      elem.setAttribute("href", '<?php echo "/newPage.php"; ?>');

      elem.innerHTML = 'not used.'

      // Append the custom element to the current row
      row.appendChild(elem);
    }
  }
}

I thought it would create the icons and text, but it just creates an empty square outline (from the CSS that was removed)
I put a delay on the creation of the custom tag and it generated them properly, but when I resized it became the empty square again.
Basically, I think when I create the tag it stops checking for the attributes, so I need to set the attributes when the element is created, not after it is.

Side-note: Use querySelectorAll which allows the usage of forEach instead of a for loop. More performant instead of nesting for-loops as well.

@tacoshy there's 0 benefit to use forEach, and several drawbacks.

@Evert Readability beats performance 99% of the time.

@connexo yes, that's one of the drawbacks. I agree performance is probably less important.

Kaiido is right, you can not use the constructor to do (some) DOM operations when you do
createElement("<div-item"), because that element is in memory and only gets created in the DOM
when you do appendChild(elem)
appendChild is also not what you want; use modern append (appends multiple DOM nodes, but was not supported in good old Internet Explorer)
Because you do not want to call append(Child) inside the loop, every call will probably cause DOM-repaints and reflows.
I focussed below code on the pain points; you can add your own stuff
Note: the connectedCallback has a potentiual DOM issue when trying to read lightDOM,
not in this snippet.
98 out of 100 developers get it wrong because they don't know what the connectedCallback does 100%
See my blogbost


<div id="row1" class="row">FOO</div>
<div id="row2" class="row">BAR</div>
<div id="row3" class="row">BAZ</div>

<script>
  customElements.define('div-item', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let src = this.getAttribute("src");
      this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .innerHTML = `<img src="${src}" style="width:40px">` + this.textContent.trim();
    }
  });

  var rows = [...document.getElementsByClassName("row")];
  rows.map(row => {
    row.innerHTML = ''; // delete FOO, BAR in row
    const length = Math.ceil((window.innerWidth - 60) / 120);
    console.log(row.id, "add", length, "div-items");
    const items = Array(length).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
      let elem = document.createElement("div-item");
      elem.setAttribute("src", "//we-are-all.github.io/sheep.svg");
      elem.append(row.id, "-", index);
      return elem;
    });
    row.append(...items); // append to row ONCE!!
  })
</script>




"every call will probably cause DOM-repaints and reflows." that would only be true if the constructor did request the computed styles on the page, and if it does, chances are they need it to be in the DOM.

Don't new DOM nodes cause a layout shift?

Not until the styles are recalc no.

Don't use map if you're not interested in the mapped array. Use forEach then.

Alas my focus is often on best GZipped code; that is my only motivation for using map. Yes, I know, its stupid, but its like an addiction, I can easily spend a whole day on getting rid of 2 more bytes...........  https://dev.to/dannyengelman/file-size-web-component-because-size-does-matter-3d3k

The constructor is called inside the createElement() call (or during upgrade if the element was parser inserted).
So by the time you call the setAttribute() method, the constructor has already been called and your element's shadow has already been built, without the attribute values.
Instead you want to the shadow content of your element during its connectedCallback:


class Item extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.src = this.getAttribute("src");
        this.link = this.getAttribute("href");
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
        this.text = this.textContent.trim();

        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>/* Styles excluded */</style>
        <div>
            <a href='${this.link}'>
                <div class="bg">
                    <img src="${this.src}" alt="${this.text}">
                </div>
                <p>${this.text}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('div-item', Item);


function createDivItems() {
  // Get all elements with the class name "row"
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

  // Iterate over each row element
  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    var row = rows[j];

    // Remove all existing div-item elements from the row
    row.innerHTML = '';

    // Create and add elements based on the window width
    for (var i = 0; i < (window.innerWidth - 60); i += 120) {
      // Create a new custom element
      // Note: the options argument of createElement only takes an 'is' property
      var elem = document.createElement("div-item"); 

      // Set attributes for the custom element
      elem.setAttribute("src", "assets/not found.png");
      elem.setAttribute("href", "/newPage.php");

      elem.innerHTML = 'not used.'

      // Append the custom element to the current row
      row.appendChild(elem);
    }
  }
}

createDivItems();
<div class="row"></div>



